# DB / TABLE specific query results location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How can I create a query result location specific to a database / table when I am querying data using AWS console. At the moment I see "query results location" in settings but it seems to be a global setting which is applicable to all databases. Is there a way to tweak the below table creation script or use any other mechanism to specify db / table specific results location when querying using aws console?

my query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SAMPLE (
  customer_id    String,
  customer_name String

) 
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 's3://<bucket>/files/';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the new Work Groups feature. Create a new work group and set its result location, and use this work group when running queries from the console.

It won't be something you would do per query, but I'm not sure if that is what you're asking for.

Running queries from the console is more limited than using the API, as you probably know when using the `StartQuertExecution` API call you can specify the output location for that specific query to be any location on S3, but when the console is an application that abstracts away all of that and is not really made to support the full API.